# DeepAR+ in google colab

Tags: deep-learning

I'm working on a time series forecasting project in Google Colab, and I originally planned to use the DeepAR+ model from GluonTS. However, I've noticed that the current version of GluonTS does not include DeepAR+. I'm looking for alternative approaches or libraries to perform time series forecasting in my Colab environment using DeepAR+.

I've searched for solutions but haven't found an alternative way to use DeepAR+ in google colab. If anyone has experience with alternative methods or libraries for time series forecasting in Google Colab, I'd appreciate your insights and suggestions.

I dont want any alternative model for the replacement of DeepAR+.I want to work with this model in colab.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.